# Error while playing video in slow Motion using android-FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, video, protocol-buffers, android-ffmpeg

It says Protocol not found

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", selectedImageUri.toString(), "-filter_complex", "[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]", "-map", "v]",
                "-map", "[a]", "-b:v", "2097k", "-r", "60", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", fileName.getAbsolutePath()};

        int rc = FFmpeg.execute(complexCommand);
        Log.e(TAG, "convert Video Result is: "+rc );
```

Comment: can you attach the logcat information ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all tell me which library you are using and are you importing the right module because sometimes its missing some native libs, on the other hand Try using Filter Complex like this, please use the following command and let me know the results

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y","-i",selectedImageUri.toString(),"-filter_complex","[0:v]setpts=2.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.5[a]","-map","[v]","-map","[a]","-threads","4","-preset","ultrafast",fileName.getAbsolutePath()};
```

> Dont forget to save your video output in internal package directory
> inside Android folder

Comment: while using this command it say "Protocol not found" i am using this library{ implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.4' }

Comment: What android versions are you targeting?, also can you attach the mobile-ffmpeg log while executing the command? also try using this module (mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl-4.4.LTS) it support old version and some other gpl libraries are included aswell

Comment: I am using android 11 but i have also tried on android 9 same error occurs while in the grade i set the "minSdkVersion 24" and "targetSdkVersion 30".  in logcat result is   {  Did you mean file:content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A38845?
2021-06-24 11:38:52.603 11791-11791/com.world.technologies.labbaik.latersms E/AudioExtractorDecoder: convert Video Result is: 1 }

Comment: save your video output in internal package directory inside Android folder, and use this mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl-4.4.LTS module , and are you getting result in older then android 9 ?

Comment: thanxsss bro .....it was the storage issue i save the video output in internal package directory inside Android folder that work for me

Comment: thanks i can edit my answer, plz marked as accepted thanks :)